# how to awk pattern as variable and loop the result?

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I assign a keyword as variable, and need to awk from a file using this variable and loop. The file has millions of lines.

i have tried the code below.

```
   DEVICE="DEV2"
    while read -r line
    do
    echo $line

    X_keyword=`echo $line | cut -d ',' -f 2  | grep -w "X" |  cut -d '=' -f2`

   echo $X_keyword

   done <<< "$(grep -w $DEVICE $config)"

   log="Dev2_PRT.log"

   while read -r file
    do

        VALUE=`echo $file | cut -d '|' -f 1`
        HEADER=`echo $VALUE | cut -c 1-4`
        echo $file


        if [[ $HEADER = 'PTR:' ]]; then

            VALUE=`echo $file | cut -d '|' -f 4`
            echo $VALUE
            XCOORD+=($VALUE)
            ((X++))
        fi

    done <<<  "awk /$X_keyword/ $log"
```

expected result:

the log files content lots of below:
PTR:1|2|3|4|X_keyword
PTR:1|2|3|4|Y_rest .....

Filter the X_keyword and get the field no 4.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately your shell script is simply the wrong approach to this problem (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219 for some of the reasons why) so you should set it aside and start over.

To demonstrate the solution, lets create a sample input file:

```
$ seq 10 | tee file
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

and a shell variable to hold a regexp that's a character list of the chars 5, 6, or 7:

```
$ var='[567]'
```

Now, given the above input, here is the solution for how to `g/re/p pattern as variable and count how many results`:

```
$ awk -v re="$var" '$0~re{print; c++} END{print "---" ORS c+0}' file
5
6
7
---
3
```

If that's not all you need then please edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: Sounds good, please do go ahead and create then post the missing [mcve].